# After submitting the form, user can still edit it. I want to enable the feature of timer that after 2 hours of submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, mongodb, handlebars.js

I am using Nodejs, handlebar, jquery and mongodb/mongoosse for database for my project.

After submitting the form, user can still edit it. I want to enable a feature of timer that after 2 hours of submission the user cannot edit the form and is locked. How to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this, you can create a new Schema that has the user id (just it), and then use the expires property. So it will be something like this:

```
const editable = new mongoose.Schema({
  userId: String,
  createdAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now(), expires: 3600*2}
});
const Editable = mongoose.model('Editable', editable)
```

Now, when you save a new user, asynchronously create the Editable:

```
const user = new User(data)
user.save().then(async(userData) => {
  const editable = new Editable({userId: userData.id})
  await editable.save()
})
```

Then you'll need to create a middleware function that checks if the document actually exists. It could be something like this:

```
function isEditable(userId){
  Editable.countDocuments({userId : userId}, function (err, data) {
    if (data > 0){
      return true
    }else{
      return false
    }
  });
}
```

With this example the user will have two hours to edit the form, since after two hours, the document with his id is going to be deleted and the `isEditable()` function will return false.

When the user tries to edit the form you can implement the function like this:

```
router.get('/edit-form/:id', function(req, res, next){
  const user_id = req.params.id // This is an example of the get router to the edition form which takes the user id as a parameter

  if(isEditable(user_id)){ //Implementation of the function above
    //Render the form so the user can change it
  }else{
    res.status(403).send("Not allowed") //Status forbidden with a message
  }
})
```

This is just an example, you can implement the isEditable() function where you want, for example, in the post request of the edition.

Comment: Thanks @ezeKG!
Just in the end I don't want the document gets deleted from database after 2 hours. I want to keep the document for the respective user only that he just wontt be able to edit it. Means edit option will be locked permanently. 

What changes need to do?

Comment: The document that is going to be deleted is not the one that has the user information, just the Editable, with the user Id. As I said, to implement it, you need to add the function isEditable() as a middleware. I'll edit my answer with an example

Comment: This is because in mongo, you can't change a property after certain time. For example, is impossible to change a boolean from true to false after two hours.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Also in last; router added the condition after it won't be editable in 'else' condition, instead of sending some "Not allowed" I want to still render the same page this time to just 'VIEW' it. I will have to make two separate pages one for 'EDIT' page in 'if' condition and one for 'VIEW' in 'else' condition which I don't want to. Since the database will become more heavy. Can't I just achieve that within one page?

Comment: @VikasYadav I'll suggest doing it with two deferent pages. However, you can achive that by rendering with some bool value like this: `res.render('file', {edit: true})`, and then, depending on the template used, create an if statement. in handlebars would be: `{{if edit}} <!-- Edition Form --> {{else}} <-- View Data --> {{/if}}`.

Comment: Perfect! Will try this for sure.